# what to do with BufferedWriter object when writing to a file in external storage

Tags: android

i am writing a string to a file in android using :

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(order));
        writer.append(placedOrder);
```

whether i use

```
writer.write(placedOrder); // or
writer.append(placedOrder);
```

the data of the file is erased every time i run this code.
I want to add the data to the end of file.

Ex: When i run first time :

```
file output
My
```

Ex: When i run second time :

```
file output becomes
My
Name
```

Ex: When i run third time :

```
file output
My
Name
is
```

Ex: When i run fourth time :

```
file output
My
Name
is
Hisham.
```

and so on. Like having a record of all previous outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code uses FileWriter with default append mode set to false. You need to use the constructor in which you can set append to true:

> **public FileWriter (File file, boolean append) Since: API Level 1**
>
> Creates a FileWriter using the File file. The parameter append
>   determines whether or not the file is opened and appended to or just
>   opened and overwritten.
>
> Parameters
>   file    : the non-null File to write bytes to.
>   append  : indicates whether or not to append to an existing file.